# How can I adjust the frequently used items in the Explorer jumplist?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

At the bottom of the window in w7 is start bar, there are icons and when right click is done on an icon of an application there is list of recently open. I want to modify of list of recently open for explorer, where or how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I've no Windows 7 here right now, but I would do it like this way: create a document with an unique name. e.g. foobar_458293834231.txt and search in the registry (<kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> → "regedit") with F3 for the pattern. You will find a key value "recently open", or similar.</strike>

The keys are not, as you already mentioned it, stored in the registry of Windows. My Fault.

I've found the program [JumpListExtender](http://code.google.com/p/jumplist-extender/) very useful for your case. You can modify the Recent Open, the Pinned Items and the Jump List itself.

Comment: It does not store these values in the registry

Comment: Updated my answer.